# how to paste sonar link on jenkins

Tags: sonarqube

I have set up jenkins with sonar to analyse my project which is in ANT.

I invoked the "Staandalone sonar analysis" with the path to the properties file and it runs fine, but after the test completes it does not create the sonar folder to see the results so how do i make the sonar link available to my end users on the jenkins page so that they can easily click to see the results

Answer (score 1):

You're facing this limitation: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1522

We have several issues opened on this "link" topic, and we'll work on them all during the next sprint on the Jenkins sprint (you can find and watch them on [our JIRA instance](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20SONARPLUGINS%20AND%20component%20=%20%22Jenkins%20/%20Hudson%22%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Unresolved%20AND%20fixVersion%20is%20EMPTY%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC)).